# How to use functions in :root in SCSS for custom properties?

Tags: sass, root

I'm trying to generate custom properties in the :root using SCSS. I have a function called fluidClamp() that generates a clamp function for text sizes.  It accepts a minimum value and a maximum value.

However, I can't get any functions to work in SCSS when they're used inside :root{}.

For example:

```
:root {
   --text-s: fluidClamp(1.4, 1.6);
   --text-m: fluidClamp(1.6,1.8);
}
```

It completely ignores the function, even though the function works everywhere else. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

This is a change in SCSS v3.5.0.
You need to [interpolate](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) your function calls:

```scss
:root {
   --text-s: #{fluidClamp(1.4, 1.6)};
   --text-m: #{fluidClamp(1.6,1.8)};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use function in your `:root` pseudo element.

To achive your goal, you need to declare in your `:root` the basic rules, like:

```
$text_s: 1.4;
$text_m: 1.6;

:root{ 
  --text-s: $text_s;
  --text-m: $text_m;
}
```

Then in your component you can call:

```
.myClass{
  font-size: fluidClamp(var(--text-s), var(--text-m))
}
```

Hope it help.